# Show loading if there is no Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**=> Info.** Im trying to upload image which is working as expected. Now i want to show "Loading component on that image which is being uploaded on deleted. Its all integrated with backend so its async.

***=> Problem.* The images are in map function, so when i start upload, all other images also go into the Loading state while i want to show Loading only on that image where operation in performed.**

Here is what i am doing.

```
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = async (i, e) => {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      let payload = new FormData();
      payload.append("file", file);

      setLoading(true);

      const res = await API.post("/upload/uploadImage", payload, {
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
      });

      if (res.status === 200) {
        toast.success("Image Uploaded Successfully");
        setLoading(false);
      } else if (res.status === 400) {
        toast.error("Something went worng! please try again later");
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };


  return (
            <div key={fields.id} className="formDataImageInfo">
              {loading ? (
                <CircularProgress size="30%" />
              ) : (
                <div className="formDataImageInfo">
                  <img
                    className="showImages"
                    src={fields.url}
                    alt="selected"
                  />
                  <Button
                    className="deleteImagesButton"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => deleteImage(index)}
                  >
                    <DeleteIcon /> Deleted Image
                  </Button>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          );
```

Whenever i try to perform operation on Single image, all images go into the loading state[image]. **As you can see i had first image already but when i try to add another image, Loading component is shown on both images. Expected: It should show on that where operation is performed.**

Comment: are the toast messages showing but you still see the loading icon?

Comment: Yes its showing correctly